# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' while running Turnilo locally in dev mode

Tags: node.js, apache, data-visualization, allegro, druid

Turnilo is a business intelligence, data exploration and visualization web application for Druid. Turnilo is a fork of Pivot which is currently available under commercial licence only. The repository was forked from the stalled repository Swiv with the latest version of Pivot under Apache license. (https://github.com/allegro/turnilo).

I'm trying to run **Turnilo** in dev mode, by installing the necessary packages, and running the turnillo, withg druid hosted in my localsystem **(Single-cluster micro-quickstart deployment)** using the following command -

```
node turnilo --druid http://<broker-host-name>:[port]
```

But I get the following error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: did you replace `<broker-host-name>` with your broker hostname and `port` with its port number ?

Comment: Yes, I replaced it with the current URL for the current running instance of Druid.